# Auto-fill Django Forms Before Using "clean(self)" to Raise ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms

I am hoping to have my users enter an integer value for quantity, then check to see if the entered number is greater than the total quantity available. If it is greater, then the user can't place the order so a validation error will be raised. However, I am having some trouble accomplishing this.

As it stands my **models.py** looks like this:

```
class DirectInvestment(models.Model):
    offering = models.ForeignKey('company.DirectOffering', blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

The total share count is derived from `offering.current_shares_outstanding` (since it is a foreign key).

Furthermore my **forms.py** looks like this:

```
class DirectInvestmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DirectInvestment
        fields = ('offering', 'quantity')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DirectInvestmentForm, self).clean()
        print(cleaned_data)
        quantity = cleaned_data.get("quantity")
        total_available_shares = cleaned_data.get("offering.current_shares_outstanding")

        if quantity > total_available_shares:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Quantity exceeds total shares available")
```

And finally, here is the relevant bits of my **views.py**:

```
form = DirectInvestmentForm(request.POST or None)
form.fields['offering'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()    

if form.is_valid():
    investment = form.save(commit=False)

    offering = DirectOffering.objects.get(id=offering_id) # offering_id I get from the URL

    investment.offering = offering
    investment.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/investments')

context_dict['form'] = form
```

When I rum my code and submit the form I get the error:

> unorderable types: int() > NoneType()

and if I look at the Local vars I see that cleaned_data has the following:

`{'offering': None, 'quantity': 123456789}`

Any idea on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare integers to None. In your code, as offering is a ForeignKey, you are either getting and object or None (because of `blank = True` in your model definition). Then, in your cleaned method, `total_available_shares = cleaned_data.get("offering.current_shares_outstanding")` is resolving to None, and creating the error you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, I have `blank=True` because I auto-populate this field using in the views. Should I remove this?

Comment: No, you shouldnt remove this if your app needs to manage ForeignKeys in your model. But you need to except None type responses to let your app handle them. You can add a condition to assign `total_variable_shares` to 0 if it was None.